# Qt GUI becomes unresponsive emitting signals too fast

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I've got a small chat client that stores all history in an `sqlite` database. When the user clicks on the `history` tab in my application my app fetches all the relevant history and displays it in a `QWebView`. Im fetching from a background thread `dbThread` below and then sending signals to update the `QWebView` accordingly.

This works fine, until the database grows. When the database gets larger the app starts to almost crashes. GUI is unresponsive for a few seconds until everything is loaded (4-6 secs) depending on the `database` size.

I've tried to add `Qt::QueuedConnection` on the signals and also like mentioned above I'm handling all `database` queries from a `background thread`.

I'm guessing that I'm emitting signals too fast. Any ideas how to solve this?

Signals

```
connect(dbtrad, SIGNAL(addAllHistoryMessage(QString, QString, QString, QString, QString)), this, SLOT(addAllHistoryMessage(QString, QString, QString, QString, QString)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
connect(dbtrad, SIGNAL(addAllHistoryMessageInner(QString, QString, QString, QString, QString)), this, SLOT(addAllHistoryMessageInner(QString, QString, QString, QString, QString)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Code that fetches history from the sqlite database:

```
// Loads all local history
void dbThread::loadAllHistory(QString agentID, QString agentName) {
    bool ret = false;
    bool retInner = false;
    QString retVal = "";

    QDateTime dateTime = dateTime.currentDateTime();
    QString dateTimeForTodayCheck = dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");

    if (db.isOpen()) {
        QSqlQuery query(db);
        QSqlQuery queryInner(db);

        ret = query.exec(QString("SELECT channelID, sender, time, message from chatHistory WHERE sender != 'ServerMessage' AND channelID NOT LIKE '%Agent%' GROUP BY channelID order by time DESC;"));

        if (ret) {

            while (query.next()) {    
                QString channelID = query.value(0).toString();
                QString sender = query.value(1).toString();
                QString time = query.value(2).toString();
                QString msg = query.value(3).toString();


                QString timeStr;
                QString fmt = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
                QDateTime dt = QDateTime::fromString(time, fmt);
                QDateTime dtCompare = QDateTime::fromString(time, fmt);

                if(dateTimeForTodayCheck == dtCompare.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")) { // If today
                    timeStr = "Today " + dt.toString("hh:mm");
                } else {
                    timeStr = dt.toString("dd MMM yyyy");
                }

                if(sender == agentID) {
                    sender = agentName;
                }
                // Grab all the tags
                QString tempTagsForChannelID = getHistoryTagsString(channelID);

                emit addAllHistoryMessage(channelID, sender, timeStr, msg, tempTagsForChannelID);

                // Load sub-history
                retInner = queryInner.exec(QString("SELECT * from chatHistory WHERE sender != 'ServerMessage' AND channelID = '%1' and message != '%2' order by time DESC;").arg(channelID).arg(msg));

                if (retInner) {
                    while (queryInner.next()) {
                        QString channelIDInner = queryInner.value(0).toString();
                        QString senderInner = queryInner.value(1).toString();
                        QString timeInner = queryInner.value(4).toString();
                        QString msgInner = queryInner.value(2).toString();

                        QString timeStr2;
                        QString fmt = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
                        QDateTime dt = QDateTime::fromString(timeInner, fmt);
                        QDateTime dtCompare = QDateTime::fromString(timeInner, fmt);

                        if(dateTimeForTodayCheck == dtCompare.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")) { // If today
                            timeStr2 = "Today " + dt.toString("hh:mm");
                        } else {
                            timeStr2 = dt.toString("dd MMM yyyy");
                        }

                        if(senderInner == agentID) {
                            senderInner = agentName;
                        }

                        emit addAllHistoryMessageInner(channelIDInner, senderInner, timeStr2, msgInner, tempTagsForChannelID);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code to update:

```
void MainWindow::addAllHistoryMessageInner(QString channelIDInner, QString senderInner, QString timeStr2, QString msgInner, QString tempTagsForChannelID) {
    ui->webViewHistory->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("$('#history tbody').append('<tr id=\"" + channelIDInner+ "\" class=\"hiddenRow\"><td>" + senderInner + "</td><td align=\"center\">" + timeStr2 + "</td><td align=\"center\" style=\"word-wrap:break-word;\">" + msgInner.remove(QRegExp("<[^>]*>")) + "</td><td align=\"center\">" + tempTagsForChannelID + "</td></tr>');undefined");
}

void MainWindow::addAllHistoryMessage(QString channelID, QString sender, QString timeStr, QString msg, QString tempTagsForChannelID) {
    ui->webViewHistory->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("$('#history tbody').append('<tr id=\"" + channelID + "\"><td>" + sender + "</td><td align=\"center\">" + timeStr + "</td><td align=\"center\" style=\"word-wrap:break-word;\">" + msg.remove(QRegExp("<[^>]*>")) + "</td><td align=\"center\" style=\"word-wrap:break-word;\">" + tempTagsForChannelID + "</td></tr>');undefined");
}
```

**Edit: Implementation of dbThread**

```
thread = new QThread(this);
dbtrad = new dbThread();
dbtrad->moveToThread(thread);
```

**Edit 2: This is how I call `loadAllHistory`**

I create a signal:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(loadAllHistoryS(QString, QString)), dbtrad, SLOT(loadAllHistory(QString, QString)));
```

And call it like this:

```
emit loadAllHistoryS(agentID, agentName);
```

Comment: does your db connection gets created in the `dbThread`? does `dbThread` really run in a separated thread, how is it implemented?

Comment: Im opening the db connection inside `dbThread` see my implementation of the thread above :)

Comment: how do you call `loadAllHistory` ?

Comment: Update how I call it

Comment: did you start the event loop on the thread with `thread.start()`? Could it be that the result is effectively executed synchronously on the same thread instead of the background thread (causing the blocking of the main thread due to database I/O)?

Comment: FYI `QString("...").arg(...)` isn't actual parameterization of your queries (sql injection is still possible), instead use `prepare` and `bindValue`.

Comment: `QString, QString, QString, QString, QString` why dont you create a new object??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that your main thread is interrupted for every single row in the `innerQuery`.  This destroys the benefits of loading the data in separate thread. Probably the overhead of the signal/slot communication over thread boundaries is even higher than the costs of loading a single row from the database.

I would recommend to collect the rows in a `QList` instance the `while` loop. When done, push the complete result via one signal invocation to the main thread:

First declare a simple class for storing history items:

```
class HistoryItem {
    public:
        QString channelID;
        /* additonal fields omitted for brevity */
        /* also, private fields with getters and setters would be better */
}
```

Then, create a list of such objects before the `while` loop:

```
QList<HistoryItem*> innerResult;
while (queryInner.next()) {
      /* snip */
      HistoryItem* item = new HistoryItem();
      item.channelId = channelIDInner;
      /* more lines ommited */
      innerResult.append(historyItem);
}
emit historyLoaded(innerResult);
```

Obviously, you also need a matching signal definition in your worker class:

```
Q_SIGNAL void historyLoaded(QList<HistoryItem*> result);
```

---

Also as noted in the comments, you have to start the background thread with `QThread::start()`.

Comment: How would I store the results in a `QList` then somehow loop over it in the main thread?

Comment: after the thread setup code

@ratchetfreak right, I've corrected that part

Comment: Also given that it is a POD type you can store them in the QList by value, (you will need to call `qRegisterMetaType<QList<HistoryItem>>("QList<HistoryItem>");` and put `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(HistoryItem)` before you can do the signal-slot stuff though)

Comment: Cant get the signal `historyLoaded` to fire. Added it like this: `connect(dbtrad, SIGNAL(historyLoaded(QList)), this, SLOT(historyLoaded(QList)));`

Comment: The argument types are incomplete: `QList<HistoryItem*>`.

Comment: Still not firing. Ive added `void historyLoaded(QList<HistoryItem*> innerResult);` as `SLOT` and `SIGNAL` in the `mainwindow.h` also

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from continuous loading:

You only load the elements that will be in view and only request the next set when they get scrolled into view (or just at a much lower pace in the background in general).

This can for example be done with [Adding an object to the window object](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject) with the appropriate signal and letting the js trigger it when the end becomes visible.